# NSData Property in iOS not being set

Tags: objective-c

in .h file i have

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableData*  dpBytes;
```

in .m

```
@synthesize dpBytes;

NSData *bytesData = cm.msgBytes;//bytes
[fr.dpBytes appendData:bytesData];
```

but fr.dpBytes length is 0

what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fr.dpBytes = [[NSMutableData alloc ] init];`

then

`[fr.dpBytes appendData:bytesData];`

Comment: @aksh1: your answer was wrong at several places. This answer is correct. "You need to allocate space to the pointer `*bytesData` first" - nah, the pointer has already been allocated. It's the object pointed to by the pointer what needs allocation **and initialization.** Furthermore, you need an `NSMutableData` instance if you want to append to it. Also, `bytesData = cm.msgBytes;` is simply **wrong,** it leaks memory (by loosing the pointer to the previously allocated object), and it doesn't help eliminating the problem the `cm.msgBytes` is **still** `nil` if not initialized.

Comment: @H2CO3 I am not wrong at all, he must initialize NSMutableData before using append, he asked what is wrong there and I told him , I assumed he knew what is going on with cm.msgBytes. You cannot tell me i am wrong , but you can tell that my response isn't complete :).

Comment: @soryngod No. The code in your answer was incorrect. `NSData *bytesData = [[NSData alloc]init]; bytesData = cm.msgBytes;` simply causes a memory leak, it doesn't initialize `cm.msgBytes`. Also, you still don't need to "allocate memory for the pointer", because you already have allocated memory for the pointer itself by declaring it as a local or instance variable. You need memory for the underlying object.

Comment: @H2CO3 I know, I am sorry for being too hasty in answering. I saw this answer and realized that mine was wrong and removed it. I will be more careful in the future.

Comment: @H2CO3 it's his code , i copy-pasted his question and added the allocation.

Comment: @aksh1t OK, no worries at all, I just wanted to make sure you don't misunderstand the problem :)

Comment: @soryngod Your answer is correct, I'm not criticizing it by any means.

Comment: @H2CO3 ok, I only thought we were pointing him to the right direction, wasn't trying to give him a lesson.

Comment: @H2CO3 I thought you talked with me ... my mistake.

Comment: @soryngod As long as you are soryngod and not aksh1t, no, I didn't.